# Linked Data and Tagging

Tags: hyperlink, tagging, semantic-web, information-retrieval

Does linked data applications use tagging for easier information retrieval? Where to get information on this specific topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For semantic annotation (tagging) the following applications would be good starting points:

- http://gate.ac.uk/
- http://www.ontotext.com/kim

Especially the GATE system includes a lot of information and tutorials related to both POS-tagging and ontology-based semantic tagging.

And yes, once your text has been semantically tagged, it is much easier to connect it to other pieces of text using the extra semantic medatada.